# Rspec test a Validation that prevents attribute change after initial create (Rails 4, rspec 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a model where I implemented a validate to prevent change after the initial value has been set.

It works this way:

**models/deal.rb**

```
validate :quantity_not_changeable

def quantity_not_changeable
      if quantity_changed? && self.persisted?
        errors.add(:quantity,"Change of quantity is not allowed. Delete and re-create the deal.")
      end
    end
```

This works in my app. but I am trying to test this with Rspec and not managing to do it.

I tried to test this but the test fails.

```
describe Deal do

  let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

  before(:each) do
    @attr = {
      title:                              "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem",
      description:                        "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum",
      quantity:  10
    }
  end

describe "my test" do

it "fails if initial quantity is changed" do 
      msg_error = "Change of the initially defined qty is impossible"
      hash = @attr.merge(quantity: 5)
      deal = Deal.new(hash)
      expect(deal).to have(1).errors_on(:quantity)      
    end
end
```

**but I get this rspec error:**

```
Failure/Error: expect(deal).to have(1).errors_on(:quantity)
       expected 1 errors on :quantity, got 0
```

How to make this work and really test that changing the qty is not possible ?

**EDIT**

I understand now why the test is fialing but don't know how to deal with it.

If I remove self.persisted? from the code like below, the test I am using passes. so the problem comes from persisted?

```
def quantity_not_changeable
          if quantity_changed? 
            errors.add(:quantity,"Change of quantity is not allowed. Delete and re-create the deal.")
          end
        end
```

But I don't want to remove it because, I actually need it: I only want to prevent change of the field when it already has a value so I want to ignore new records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit the model:

```
validate :quantity_not_changeable, on: :update

def quantity_not_changeable
  if quantity_changed?
    errors.add(:quantity,"Change of quantity is not allowed. Delete and re-create the deal.")
  end
end
```

and then in it statement:

```
it "fails if initial quantity is changed" do 
  msg_error = "Change of the initially defined qty is impossible"
  deal = Deal.create!(@attr)
  deal.update(quantity: 5)
  expect(deal).to have(1).errors_on(:quantity)      
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still not working. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry there is check after changing respectively first of we need create object, then do update and quantity_changed? will be true, and error has been added. Just remember that new method didn't validation, but create or update methods do one.

Comment: hi Devor. i don't see the difference with Alexei answer and his did not work.

Comment: check my edit: tracked down the source of the bug: it's "persisted"

Comment: hi Mathieu. Check out my edited answer. When using simply validate function there is validation is ran after `create` method and it didn't save the entry to db and it's persisted was set to false. We need simply pass hash to `validate` method for using only for `update`. Also you don't need in `persisted?` condition for entry because after first creating that is persisted.

Comment: @Mathieu, when you removed `self.persisted?` error was add to model after call `create` method.

Comment: Hi Devor still not working! same error. I'm becoming mad.... But your strategy anyways of :on :update was cleaner so I moved to it and created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688634/rspec-test-validations-of-on-update-not-working-rails4-rspec-3

Comment: @Mathieu probably `create` method isn't **saved** entry. Try run `create!` method that raise error when entry isn't valid, or  [this recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688634/rspec-test-validations-of-on-update-not-working-rails4-rspec-3?answertab=active#tab-top) in your post

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your `Deal`, so your `persisted?` check will work, and *then* update your `quantity` attribute, so your second check `quantity_changed?` will work too:

```
it "fails if initial quantity is changed" do 
  msg_error = "Change of the initially defined qty is impossible"
  deal = Deal.create(@attr)
  deal.update(quantity: 5)
  expect(deal).to have(1).errors_on(:quantity)      
end
```

Comment: @Alexei, tried your method but still getting the same error "expected 1 errors on :quantity, got 0". Very frustrating as in the real app, when i manually try to change it I do see that my validate works as I am unable to change the value.

Comment: check my edit: tracked down the source of the bug: it's "persisted"